# Rendering Scenekit inside of Motion 5

Tags: canvas, rendering, scenekit

So from the research I have done there seems to be a way to render Scenekit in other windows instead of creating your own window through via NSRect or a .xib file.  I am trying to have Scenekit to display inside of Motion 5's canvas.  Motion 5 uses FxPlug SDK and have a method called renderOutput that displays content to the canvas.

```
- (BOOL)renderOutput:(FxImage *)outputImage  
withInfo:(FxRenderInfo)renderInfo  
{  
BOOL retval = YES;  

SCNRenderer *renderer;  

SCNScene *_scene;  

SCNNode *cameraNode;  

_scene = [SCNScene scene];  

renderer = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:renderInfo.sharedContext options:nil];  
renderer.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;  
renderer.playing = YES;  
renderer.loops = YES;  
renderer.showsStatistics = YES;  

renderer.scene = _scene;  
SCNCamera *camera = [SCNCamera camera];  
cameraNode = [SCNNode node];  
cameraNode.camera = camera;  
[_scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];  
renderer.pointOfView = cameraNode;  

renderer.sceneTime = renderInfo.time.frame;  
NSLog(@"Renderer Info: %@", renderer);  
return retval;  
}
```

The output when I display the renderer to he console shows all of the nodes, camera, and scene have memory allocated to it like so:

```
Renderer Info: <SCNRenderer 0x14ede9890: scene = <SCNScene: 0x14edc6f30>, pointOfView = <SCNNode: 0x14ed3f680 | camera=<SCNCamera: 0x14edc5260> | no child>, sceneTime = 0.000000, context = 0x108255000>
```

I have tried using SceneKit to add nodes and images to the scene and no matter what I do I cannot get anything to display on Motion 5's canvas.  I am not sure what I am missing but it seems like something is allocating data in the console but I seem to be missing an important piece here.  I understand this question is very specific but if anyone has any understanding of SceneKit and how to display SceneKit inside of Motion 5.